# JSP unable to execute javascript function included in script tag

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am writing a java web application where I have the following head tag in the jsp file.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>EECE 417 Exercise 3</title>    
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/main.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAxfoydM9lSVCJi-vhMZJ_Q3eawPjIsuLw&sensor=true">
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function initialize() {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.33152141760375,-122.04732071026367);   

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 12
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
          mapOptions);      

        var mrkID = "0";
        var gstBkNm = "Guestbook_" + mrkID; //guestbookNameString; //"default";
        var msgbox = "msgbox_" + mrkID; 
        var msglist = "msglist_" + mrkID;


        var contentString  = '#' + mrkID + '<div id="content">' +   
          '<div class="msglist" id="'+ msglist +'"></div>' + '</div>' +
          '<textarea id="'+ msgbox +'" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>' +              
          '<input type="button" value="Post" onclick="postAjaxRequest('+ 
            "'" + msgbox + "', '" + mrkID + "', '" + gstBkNm + "', '" + msglist + "'" +')"/>';  

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString

        }); 

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
            parking: {
                icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
            },
            library: {
                icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
            },
            info: {
                icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
            }
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          icon: icons['parking'].icon,  
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          title: 'Custom Marker!'
        });    

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          map.setZoom(13);
          guestbookNameString = gstBkNm;
          selectedMarkerID = mrkID;     
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          getAjaxRequest();   
        });        

        // Load the selected markers            
        alert("initialize");
        loadMarkers();
        alert("initialize1");
    }      

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I have two alerts in the code where the loadMarkers() function is called in the script. This loadMarkers() is present in the included src file (in jsp head tag which is in main.js.

for some reason, it is not able to execute the code in loadMarkers(). I have loadmarkers() in main.js as follows:

```
function loadMarkers() { 
    alert("loadMarkers"); 
    try { 
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = httpCallBackFunction_loadMarkers; 
        var url = "/resources/markers.xml"; 

        xmlHttpReq.open('GET', url, true); 
        xmlHttpReq.send(null);           
    } catch (e) { 
        alert("Error: " + e); 
    }    
}
```

The application seemed to run fine and I didn't have this problem before. It is also worth noting that getAjaxRequest() is also in the main.js file and doesn't seem to work as I had set an alert at the start of that function but it doesn't display in my browser. It would be really beneficial if I could gain some insight as to how to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have any js error in the console?

Comment: @roshiro no, there is no error in the javascript as far as I believe. I should also get to see the alert("loadMarkers") in the browser but it doesn't display it when I run the application.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make all the alerts work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roshiro/Y58d5/)

I had to include a div with id "map-canvas" in the body and move the `loadMarkers()` out of the main.js file.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! It seemed that the problem was in the calculations made in a time-critical function in my javascript that caused the markers to not show up. Appreciate the attempt! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was caused due to calculations made in Ajax request function in my javascript. It seems bizarre but after moving the calculations out from the function, the markers seemed to load properly. Still very weird that the alerts didn't show up in the browser.